# Error when trying to read the .ini file from .nsi script

Tags: reporting-services, installation, nsis, ini

I have to write a NSIS script for deployment the report on the server.It works fine when I am using **localhost**.

Now I want to send this package to my client but the problem is that I don't know the SERVER IP of the client for this purpose I have write the .ini file. The content of the ini file is

> **DeployReport.ini**

```
[SETTINGS]
ServerIp=localhost
UserName=
PassWord=
```

> **DeployReport.nsi**

```
# Script generated by DeepSofts - NSIS Script Generator
# Beginning Basic Section Script ...

Name 'DeployReport'
Icon 'modern-install-full.ico'
OutFile 'DeployReport.exe'
SilentInstall Normal
CRCCheck On

Section GetIP 0
ReadINIStr $ip "DeployReport.ini" "SETTINGS" "ServerIp"
MessageBox MB_OK "$ip"
SectionEnd    

Section Command 1
Exec '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Binn\rs.exe" -i PublishSampleReports.rss -s http://localhost/reportserver"'
SectionEnd


ComponentText 'A few details about the application that you have created'

AutoCloseWindow True

SetCompress Auto
SetDateSave On
SetDataBlockOptimize On
```

The problem is that the DeployReport.nsi script works fine untill I dont use the  **Section GetIP 0** and I am not able to find the error in the script.

Comment: It is very hard to understand what the problem is from your description. Are you getting a compiler error?

Comment: Where exactly is your .ini file located? If it is on target computer you should use destination path: $INSTDIR\DeployReport.ini for function ReadINIStr

Comment: No,the .ini file is current working directory..

Answer (score 0):

You should use the full path to the .ini (`"$exedir\DeployReport.ini"`)